# How to change the FileSplit size in new Hadoop api

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

As in new Hadoop api, the number of mappers can't be explicitly set, I'd like to change the SplitSize to a smaller number than the default so that more mappers get executed. How can I do that in the new Hadoop api?

I have tried the following , but it doesn't work

```
 conf.setLong(FileInputFormat.Split_MAXSIZE, 16 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change below parameters as per your requirement.

```
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
```

and

```
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize
```

Have a look at this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/constant-values.html#org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.SPLIT_MAXSIZE) for more details.

Comment: I set this value in my code, but it looks like it is not effective!

Comment: What's your hadoop version? I have provided parameters in hadoop 2.x version.

Comment: Did you change configuration file? If that does not work,   Pass these values from command line while executing the jar.

Comment: Passing them from the command line works but when I programmatically set them it doesn't work and I need to programmatically set it. Should I set both parameters cause I only set the max parameter?

Comment: For your requirement, max is enough. Set the minimum value in configuration file,which is common to all jobs

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize`. If it does not work, please share your code and I will have a look at it.